# Should I avoid creating a menu which gets titles and url(href) values from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, menu

I would like to create a table which has column like title,target and I would list all elements on top of the page as links. Is there a huge drawback of doing this?

Comment: no, there is nothing wrong in that.

Comment: Not at all. It's quite common, though you may consider caching data which rarely changes for efficiency's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making a menu for your own pages, that could be a bad idea.

If you store all your pages with some ID on the database, you can just make a reference to them on the menu.

But if you plan to be able to make links to another pages, than I see no problem in storing urls on the database.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, yes. Each item would be an individual http request... Not to mention that you wouldnt be able to utilize caching with that setup!

Unless of course you were to load them via ajax which then sends them all to the page as say a JSON object.

I have never known the need for a menu constructed in this manner though. If you had so many different options for a user to choose from a degree of optimisation would need to be done.

Unless I am misunderstanding your objectives though :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a flat-file storage for this type of configuration. I have worked on projects Where we opted to store client navigation menus in .yml files, so we could quickly load custom navigation menus for specific clients. We also added a caching layer so we would check cache first before retrieving from the flat-file.

For the yaml parser we used [sfYaml](http://components.symfony-project.org/yaml/), which is a stand alone yaml parser and has worked well under any number of usages.